# Create PDF of whole webview Android

Tags: android, pdf, webview

Currently attempting to include a PDF export feature for my application. This involves populating a HTML template, putting that into a WebView, then writing the contents of that WebView to a PDF using adapted code from here: [How to create PDF from webView, which is hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000773/how-to-create-pdf-from-webview-which-is-hidden) - however when the PDF is generated I am only getting the visible area of the  WebView, so information off-screen is being cut off.

Here is my code, is there a way I can capture the data from the whole WebView?

```
public void createPDF() {
    PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
    PdfDocument.PageInfo inf = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(A4_width, A4_height, 1).create();
    PdfDocument.Page page = doc.startPage(inf);
    Canvas c = page.getCanvas();
    int webWidth = htmlViewer.getWidth();
    float scale = A4_width / (float) webWidth;
    c.save();
    c.scale(scale, scale);

    htmlViewer.draw(c);
    c.restore();
    doc.finishPage(page);

    File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
    String name = requestID + ".pdf";
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            File file = (new File(dir, name));
            if(!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            doc.writeTo(fos);
            doc.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "PDF made");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) { fos.close(); }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```